# Why does this piece of code not give error?

Tags: c, for-loop, syntax

```
void main() {
    int i, j=6;
    for(; i=j ; j-=2 )
        printf("%d",j);
}
```

By following regular pattern, there should be a **condition** after first semicolon, but here it is **initialization**,so this should have given an error. 
How is this even a valid format?

But the output is `642`

Comment: It should be an *expression* and assignment is an expression.

Comment: There is no inutialization, there is an assignment. Btw `void main` is non-standard.

Comment: It's basically shorthand for `(i=j) != 0` since `0` is `false`

Comment: Why then the code not print 0,-2,-4.......and so on

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. If a book told you to use `void main()`, find a better book.

Comment: If you compile with clang using `-Wall` you'll get two warnings. The first because you messed up the declaration of `main`. The second because you messed up the `for` statement (used an assignment as a conditional expression). If you aren't compiling with `-Wall` and/or you are ignoring warnings, then I can't adequately express my opinion about that (due to the *"be nice"* policy).

Comment: @user3386109 what actually -Wall stands for

Comment: It supposed to stand for *"enable all warnings"*, but in reality it just enables some additional warnings. There's also `-Wextra` and `-Weverything` which will enable even more warnings.

Comment: @user3386109 ok. Got it. Thanks

Comment: @Nitish Prajapati: C has no such thing as a dedicated "condition". Every "condition" is basically an arbitrary (non-void) expression that will be implicitly tested for equality to zero. `i=j` is a non-void expression, which means that it can perfectly fine serve as a "condition".

Comment: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc main returns zero(0) always.correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: wrong. if it's always 0 then no need to use the return type int

Comment: @NitishPrajapati:  You can upvote all answers that help you and accept one of them by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me correct the terminology, the `i=j` is an ***assignment***, not an *initialization.*

That said, let's analyze the `for` loop syntax first.

> `for` `(` *clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3* `)` *statement*

So, the *expression-2* should be an "expression".

Now, coming to the syntax for statement having assignment operator

> *assignment-expression:*
>  *conditional-expression*
>  *unary-expression
>   assignment-operator assignment-expression*

So, as the spec `C11` mentions in chapter §6.5.16, the assignment operation is also an *expression* which fits perfectly for the *expression-2* part in `for` loop syntax.

Regarding the *result*,

> An
>   assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment,

so, `i=j` will basically assign the value of `j` to `i` and then, the value of `i` will be used for condition checking, (i.e., non-zero or zero as TRUE or FALSE).

**TL;DR** Syntactically, there's no issue with the code, so no error is generated by your compiler.

---

Also, for a hosted environment, `void main()` should be `int main(void)` to be conforming to the standard.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks :)

Comment: As against this, sometimes **main()** contains **parameters** [not void].what are those for?please explain in detail.

Comment: @NitishPrajapati that was in reference to `void main()`. that does not either process command line arguments, right?

Comment: I'm failing to get what you are trying to say. I've heard the term **command line arguments**. But just heard of it. I actually don't know what's their purpose and what they do, and why is it that it has to be main(int argc, char **argv)only. What purpose argc and argv serve.

Comment: I've also seen it in reference to int main() and not just void main()

Comment: @NitishPrajapati OK, gimme some time

Answer (score 3):

`i=j` is also an expression, the value of which is the value of `i` after the assignment. So it can serve as a condition.

You'd normally see this type of cleverness used like this:

```
if ((ptr = some_complex_function()) != NULL)
{
  /* Use ptr */
}
```

Where some programmers like to fold the assignment and check into one line of code. How good or bad this is for readability is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Oh ok ok! Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Btw is ptr a pointer or just a variable. I assume its just a variable

Comment: @NitishPrajapati, I'm not sure what you mean by "or". A pointer is just a variable that can hold an address to a specific type.

Comment: i meant that is it a **pointer variable** or a **non pointer variable**

Comment: @NitishPrajapati, well the comparison to NULL gives it away, I think :) A pointer.

Comment: can you please explain what does that mean. "comparison to NULL givers it away, the pointer"

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not contain a syntax error, hence the compiler accepts it and generates code to produce `642`.

The condition `i=j` is interpreted as `(i = j) != 0`.

To prevent this and many similar error patterns, enable more compiler warnings and make them fatal with:

```
gcc -Wall -W -Werror
```

If you use `clang`, use `clang -Weverything -Werror`

Comment: Got it.Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question.

To really understand this, you better know how C codes are executed in computer:
First, the compiler will compile the C code into assembly code, then assembly codes will be translated into machine code, which can run in main memory directly.

As for your code:

```
void main() {
    int i, j=6;
    for(; i=j ; j-=2 )
        printf("%d",j);
}
```

To figure out why the result is 642, We want to see its assembly code.

Using VS debugging mode, we can see:

[image]

Especially look at this:

```
010217D0  mov         eax,dword ptr [j]  
010217D3  mov         dword ptr [i],eax  
010217D6  cmp         dword ptr [i],0  
010217DA  je          main+4Fh (010217EFh)
```

The four lines of assembly code correponding to the C code "i=j", it means, first move the value of j to register eax, then move the value of register eax to i(since computer can not directly move the value of j to i, it just use register eax as a bridge), then compare the value of i with 0, if they are equal, jump to 010217EFh, the loop ends; if not, the loop continues.

So actually it's first an assignment, then a comparision to decide whether the loop is over; as 6 declines to 0 ,the loop finally stops, I hope this can help you understand why the result is 642 :D

Comment: Thanks. Yes it was helpful. I got the concept behind it